# Background worker and progress bar not working properly

Tags: c#, encryption, progress-bar, backgroundworker

Hi was trying to have a progress bar to load for my encryption and compression application . 
I'm trying to use the background worker to update the progress bar on the time taken for the compression and encryption processed but somehow the application show the encrytion fail msg box that i have included inside the button rather than a success.

This is the code for my button

```
    private void lockButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (this.passwordtextBox.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a password!");
        }
        else if (this.retypeTextBox.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please retype password!");
        }
        else if (this.passwordtextBox.Text == this.retypeTextBox.Text)
        {
            details = new Details();
            details.SetPassword(this.passwordtextBox.Text);

            if (this.EncryptionComboBox.Text == "AES")
            {
                details.SetEncryption(this.EncryptionComboBox.Text);

                if (details.GetResult() == true)
                {
                    // Start the background worker
                    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
                }

                if (details.GetResult() == true)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Lock Success!");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Lock Unsuccess! Please try again");
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The password and verified password does not match!");
        }
    }
```

And this is my background worker code

```
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        //declare lockcontroller to be used
        LockController lControl = new LockController();

        //run zipfile method and store result to fName
        lControl.compress(ifile, details);
        lControl.Encrypt(details);
        lControl.LockCleaner(details);
        int i = 100;

        // Report progress to 'UI' thread
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);

        // Simulate long task
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(0000);            
    }
```

I was wondering where it went wrong. progress bar and both encryption not working..

Comment: You pretty fundamentally misunderstand how BGW works.  And what 0000 means.  Educate yourself, this is not the right place.

Comment: My advice would be to get the encoding code working without an BackgroundWorker you can add one to the working code later. I'd also create some test code to get the Backgroundworker to show a progress bar increase and add the encoding code later.

Answer (score 3):

1. Use string.IsNullOrEmpty(string) instead of something == ""
2. You have no Worker Progress Event setup
3. It appears you added your background worker via the UI Designer - create these in code - much cleaner
4. kmcc049 is right - I don't see a completed handler either
5. Check this link for more info on how to do this.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

Answer (score 2):

when you execute this line  `backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();`
it immediately returns and executed the next line. You need to subscribe to the RunWorkerCompleted event for your message box.